# Android SwipeRefreshLayout, how to prevent double swipe

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I am implementing a SwipeRefreshLayout in my app. 
I have succesfully implemented the OnRefreshListener and I am able to correctly refresh the ListView items.

My problem is that if I swipe down, while the SwipeRefreshLayout is refreshing, it starts a new refresh animation and a new refresh procedure. The resulting animation is bad and the progress wheel seems not to be displayed correctly.
I would like to reproduce the gmail app behavior. If you pull down to refresh there, you cannot pull down again while the mail list is refreshing.
I would like to prevent a second swipe down if the list is refreshing.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a boolean flag that indicates if its already refreshing.

That way you can ignore the second swipe while the first is already running.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

Seeing the problem is for the animation and not for the task.

Have you tried calling setRefreshing(false) on the second swipe? did it cancel both animations or only the second one?

If the first case, what if you call

```
setRefreshing(false);
setRefreshing(true);
```

If that isnt working maybe you can call

```
setEnabled(false)
```

When the first swipe, so it will be locked until it finish and then you call

```
setRefreshing(false);
setEnabled(true)
```

Let me know if something works.

Comment: I have tried using a flag in the onRefresh() method. That way I can prevent a new refresh task to be executed, but the animation is still displayed. If I pull down while the progress wheel is displayed, I can still see a new wheel appearing.

Comment: `setEnabled(false)` is the perfect solution. thx. that saved my day!